# How to utilize partial index in MongoDB find() query with $exists false condition?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Can MongoDB use a partial index with "exists" true  condition when checking for existence of a field with $exists false?

Trying to make use of partial index for a field which exists on a very small subset of documents.
Created a partial index with {"field1": {"$exists": true}}. But query db.coll.find("field1: { {$exists: false}}, I don't see it using index. Is there a way I can make it use index.

Comment: By definition you've created an index that does not have the data that you are querying for. Therefore the index cannot be used because your results would not be returned. If you want to find that data with an index, why are you excluding it by making the index partial?

Comment: Oh, that explains why it can not be used. 1% of documents will have this field (collection is. big with millions of documents), so exploring with partial index , extra index size would be smaller.

Comment: If only `1%` of the documents have `field1` then that implies `99%` of documents would match the query `{"field1": {"$exists": false}}`. You would not want to use an index in that situation since it would slow the query down compared to doing a collection scan directly.